# Why can the function $f(x)=||A\vec{x}-\vec{b}||^2$ be rewritten as $\vec{x}^tA^tA\vec{x}−\vec{x}^tA^t\vec{b}−\vec{b}^tA\vec{x}+||\vec{b}||^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces, binomial-theorem

Someone answered a question introducing this transformation of the function  $f(x)=||A\vec{x}-\vec{b}||^2$ ; but I cannot get the idea why and how. Looks a bit like a binomial expansion, but I can't grasp the transpose multiplication.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for any real vector $v$, $\|v\|^2 = v^Tv$.  So, now we have
$$
\|Ax - b\|^2 = \\
(Ax - b)^T(Ax - b)=\\
(x^TA^T - b^T)(Ax - b) =\\
x^TA^TAx - x^TA^Tb - b^TAx - b^Tb =\\
x^TA^TAx - x^TA^Tb - b^TAx - \|b\|^2
$$
as desired.